# Database design issue with different hierarchical structures to store

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

I have a slight issue with a database design. I don't how to solve a problem with different hierarchical structure of companies I have to take care of and store these information. I am trying to make database that can store info about people who I have already contacted or I am going to contact. I also need to store details regarding the company that a particular person work for. The problem is that companies have different structures. It may also be a university with schools and faculties, research institutes if I consider an academic role of someone's job. For instance, a person works at the Univetsity of Oxford, at Schoold of Languages that is part of Faculty of Something. Now, another person may work for government etc in Department of Something. How would you solve this design related issue? I have to do it and I am not quite experienced with it yet.
I hope it is not confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that it will be either in MS Sql 2008 or MS ACCESS 2010--most likely the second option. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact answer to your question really depends on the precise requirements that you are yet to provide. That being said, the following idea is probably not a bad starting point from which to develop your database model:

[image]

- Organizations form a "wood" and each "tree" in that wood has "root" with NULL in PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID.
- A single person can work for more than one organization and (of course) an organization can employ multiple persons. This many-to-many relationship is represented by a junction table WORKS_AT.

Comment: Hi Branko,
I understood the second point in the list; that is, many to many relationship. However, I did not follow your explanation on Organization table. I did not follow your description on how Organization table is designed. Is PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID a link to another table, if it's foreign key?

Comment: @ZikO This is a classical way of representing hierarchies in relational databases: a foreign key to the same table (as indicated by the FK1 in front of the PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID). Let's say you need to represent a government/department/office hierarchy: you'll have `government {ORGANIZATION_ID = 1, PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID = NULL}`, `department {2, 1}`, `office {3, 2}`. If you need to add another office under the same department, you can do it like this: `office {4, 2}`. And if you need to add another department and an office under it: `department {5, 1}`, `office {6, 5}`. Etc, etc...

Comment: I think I have understood that. So if I have another organization let's say university/faculty.school, then I'd have university {7,NULL}, faculty1 {8,7}, school1 {9,8}, school2 {10,8}, school3 {11,8}, faculty2 {12,7}, school_A {13,12}, school_B {14,12} etc. Is that correct? I hope I've understood that ;p Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It really helped me with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear that the fact that contacts' organizations may have different kinds of structures is relevant to your database design.

I would start with something such as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Contact (
  ContactId int,
  OrganizationId int,
  LastName varchar(50),
  FirstName varchar(50),
  etc...
)

CREATE TABLE Organization (
  OrganizationId int,
  OrganizationTypeId int,
  Name varchar(50),
  StreetAddress varchar(100),
  etc...
)

CREATE TABLE OrganizationType (
  OrganizationTypeId int,
  Name varchar(50),
  NonProfit bit,
  etc...
)
```

In the above scenario, you can associate contacts with a particular organization and you can classify organization according to different categories if that is important to you.

Comment: Hi Dan,
I don't know. Perhaps from my description, it does not look relevant to database design. However, when I am going to query a database, I need to know where a person works with details. The details I am talking about are company name, department, office, or faculty, school and university, or institute and university etc. with contact details.

Comment: Ziko, I understand that you need the organization with which your contact is associated.  That's why I included the "OrganizationId" field in the Contact table to link to an organization.  What I did not understand is why the type of the organization (company, university, etc.) matters.  That's why I included an OrganizationType table that allows you to describe or categorize the organization with which a contact is associated.  You could also add a "Position" table that could describe your contact's position (department, title, role, etc.) within his associated organization.